Javascript and Excel DB
I made a Javascript nodejs project that stores data in Excel.
I can access all columns in the entire file without any problems, but the value of the cells containing time information(12:30) is given as numbers(0.6423611111111112).
Is it possible to import this time value in time format(12:30) into the Javascript environment?
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

const workbook = XLSX.readFile('file.xlsx');
 
var allPages= []
workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName)
{
  var XL_row_object =
  XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
  allPages.push(XL_row_object)
})
 
console.log(allPages[0][1].time)

These codes did not produce the results I wanted.

Can you share with us what did it produce exactly? is it an error? or the date in a different format? because time values are often stored as fractions of a day

So it doesn't seem that the sheet_to_row_object_array is part of the api?
Anyways, the issue you're seeing is probably due to that very functions way of decoding rows. Let's say it treats all rows as ints/numbers, and it then encounters ":". Granted, I don't know if the library is clever enough, such that it makes type assertions, but my guess is that there's some common algorithm somewhere and that it doesn't.
I think a better bet is to use sheet_to_csv and then manually split on "," and cast to the desired type (Date in your case).
*Edit*
You may want to look at array object method map. It'll do the forEach and assignment in one command.
*Edit*
Ah, I found the sheet_to_row_object_array function in the source code, however it's just an alias of sheet_to_json. If we read the documentation, we can pass a options object to that function. So if you pass it an options object with the dateNF field set to your date format, it may resolve your issue.

Thanks Tim Jensen, the issue was resolved based on the information you provided.
